# Format UITextField as user types - Feet/Inches

Tags: swift

I have a UITextField that when a user taps on it, it shows the decimal keyboard. I also have a UISwitch that toggles between metric/imperial. This switch changes a UILabel from kg->lb and cm->ft

What I would like to do is that if the UISwitch is in the imperial position, automatically format the height UITextField to show 6'1" as the user types.

Example: If I type just the number 6 in the height text field, the full text in that field would be 6'0". If I type 6 and then 1, the full text would show 6'1".

Thanks

Comment: So do you know about the UITextFieldDelegate?

Comment: Yes but not a lot. I am new to Swift

Comment: Thanks. I will work it out.